# How to de-saturate a color defined by RGB in declarative QML

Tags: qt, colors, qml, qtquick2, hsl

Using QtQuick, is it possible to take an existing color defined by RGB and desaturate it without resorting to Javascript?

Comment: If you just want to desaturate something on screen, you could use http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtgraphicaleffects-desaturate.html

Answer (score 3):

```
function desaturate(colorString)
{
    let c = Qt.darker(colorString, 1.0);
    return Qt.hsla(c.hslHue, 0.0, c.hslLightness, c.a);
}
```

Comment: Is `Qt.darker` really the only way to get a color type from a string in JS?

Comment: Well you could use `Qt.lighter` 

Answer (score 1):

Seeing how QtQuick runs on top of a Javascript engine, I'd say it is not possible to do *anything* in QML without resorting to Javascript.

In order to adjust the saturation you will have to convert RGB to HSL color and then back to RGB. QML has `Qt.hsla()` for the latter, but last time I checked it didn't provide a conversion from RGB to HSL, so I ended up using this:

```
function rgbToHsl(r, g, b) {
  r /= 255
  g /= 255
  b /= 255
  var max = Math.max(r, g, b), min = Math.min(r, g, b)
  var h, s, l = (max + min) / 2
  if (max == min) {
    h = s = 0
  } else {
    var d = max - min
    s = l > 0.5 ? d / (2 - max - min) : d / (max + min)
    switch (max) {
    case r:
      h = (g - b) / d + (g < b ? 6 : 0)
      break
    case g:
      h = (b - r) / d + 2
      break
    case b:
      h = (r - g) / d + 4
      break
    }
    h /= 6;
  }
  return {"h":h, "s":s, "l":l};
}
```

So you basically:

```
var ic = yourRGBColor.toString()
var r = parseInt(ic.substr(1, 2), 16)
var g = parseInt(ic.substr(3, 2), 16)
var b = parseInt(ic.substr(5, 2), 16)
var hsl = rgbToHsl(r, g, b)
hsl.s *= .5 // desaturate 50%
yourRGBColor = Qt.hsla(hsl.h, hsl.s, hsl.l, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just modify the color's `hsvSaturation`, or `hslSaturation` property, depending on your [color model](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcolor.html#the-hsv-color-model).

Example `Test.qml` that de-saturates a blue rectangle gradually every second (runs with `qmlscene Test.qml`):

```
import QtQuick 2.7
Item {
    width: 100
    height: 100
    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
        objectName: "precious"
        color: "#0000FF"
        Timer {
            running: true
            repeat: true
            onTriggered: parent.color.hslSaturation *= 0.8;
        }
    }
}
```

Hidden in a lot of text, between two blocks of code, these properties are actually documented in [color QML Basic Type](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-color.html).  They appear to correspond to the `qreal` versions of color component properties in C++ (names ending in `...F()`).

---

As @dtech states, the `onTriggered:...` is legally already a line of JavaScript. If you must, you can also walk down the line in C++, find the element's attribute, and modify the property there.

Example `main.cpp`, showing the above `Test.qml`, that starts with an already very de-saturated (purely in C++) blue rectangle, then gradually de-saturating it (still done in QML/JavaScript):

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQuickView>
#include <QQuickItem>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQuickView view(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/Test.qml")));
    view.show();
    if ( QObject * rectangle = view.rootObject()->findChild<QObject*>("precious") )
    {
        qreal h, s, l, a;
        rectangle->property("color").value<QColor>().getHslF( &h, &s, &l, &a );
        s *= 0.2;
        rectangle->setProperty( "color", QVariant::fromValue(QColor::fromHsvF( h, s, l, a )) );
    }
    return app.exec();
}
```

Now you could remove the apparent line of JavaScript from `Test.qml`.

---

Note that I demonstrate a very crude color animation. There is a special `ColorAnimation` tool to do better.